keras throwing error while training the LSTM
I have this input:
[['step', 'step', 'guide', 'invest', 'share', 'market', 'india'],
 ['story', 'kohinoor', 'kohinoor', 'diamond'],
 ['increase', 'speed', 'internet', 'connection', 'using', 'vpn'],
 ['mentally', 'lonely', 'solve']]

I converted each word into 50-d vector using w2v
sentence1 = [[50d vector],[50d vector],[50-d vector]...]

our input = [sentence1,sentence2,....] 

that means [[[word1],[word2],...],[[word1],[word2],...]]
Basically our input is varying with time
Now I want to train LSTM to predict our review is +ve or -ve
This is the code:
x_train=[[[word1],[word2],...[word d]],[[word1],[word2],...[word d]]]

y_train=[[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],...]

model=Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(None,50)))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dense(1,"sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss='log_loss',optimizer=Adam(),metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(question2_vector,y_train,verbose=1,epochs=5,batch_size=50)

This is model summary:
Model: "sequential_21"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ lstm_17 (LSTM)                       │ (None, 256)                 │         314,368 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_9 (Dense)                      │ (None, 1)                   │             257 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘

 Total params: 314,625 (1.20 MB)
 Trainable params: 314,625 (1.20 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B) `

When training, I get this error - what is this error am I missing anything please correct me and try to solve this issue
Thanks in advance
IndexError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)   Cell In[117], line 1  
----> 1    model.fit(question2_vector,y_train,verbose=1,epochs=5,batch_size=50)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in     filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)   119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)   120     # To get the full stack trace, call:   121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`   122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   123 finally:   124     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\data_adapters\data_adapter_utils.py:103, in <genexpr>(.0)   102 def check_data_cardinality(data):   103     num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in  tree.flatten(data))     104     if len(num_samples) > 1:   105         msg = (    106             "Data cardinality is ambiguous. "   107             "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."   108         )  

IndexError: tuple index out of range

